# Обороты со словом "позвольте"

Tags: пунктуация

Являются ли вводными обороты со словом "позвольте" ("позвольте поинтересоваться", "позвольте полюбопытствовать", "позвольте спросить" и т. п.) или это просто устойчивые сочетания?

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Это составное глагольное сказуемое.

Comment: Гран мерси.

Comment: Вспоминается м/ф про поросенка Фунтика. Замечательный диалог дядюшки Мокуса и  Белладонны.

Д.М.: "Позвольте!..."

Б.:"Не позволю!!!"

Д.М.:"Простите!..."


Б.: "Не прощу!!!"

Интересно, дядюшка Мокус использует эти слова как вводные, а Белладонна их понимает как сказуемые